# TSQL optimizing code for NOT IN

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I inherit an old SQL script that I want to optimize but after several tests, I must admit that all my tests only creates huge SQL with repetitive blocks. I would like to know if someone can propose a better code for the following pattern (see code below). I don't want to use temporary table (WITH). For simplicity, I only put 3 levels (table TMP_C, TMP_D and TMP_E) but the original SQL have 8 levels.

```
WITH
TMP_A AS (
SELECT
 ID,
 Field_X
FROM A

TMP_B  AS(
SELECT DISTINCT
 ID,
 Field_Y,
 CASE
  WHEN Field_Z IN ('TEST_1','TEST_2') THEN 'CATEG_1'
  WHEN Field_Z IN ('TEST_3','TEST_4') THEN 'CATEG_2'
  WHEN Field_Z IN ('TEST_5','TEST_6') THEN 'CATEG_3'
  ELSE 'CATEG_4'
 END AS CATEG
FROM B
INNER JOIN TMP_A
ON TMP_A.ID=TMP_B.ID),

TMP_C AS (
SELECT DISTINCT 
 ID,
 CATEG
FROM TMP_B
WHERE CATEG='CATEG_1'),

TMP_D AS (
SELECT DISTINCT 
 ID,
 CATEG
FROM TMP_B
WHERE CATEG='CATEG_2' AND ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM TMP_C)),

TMP_E AS (
SELECT DISTINCT
 ID,
 CATEG
FROM TMP_B
WHERE CATEG='CATEG_3'
 AND ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM TMP_C)
 AND ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM TMP_D))

SELECT * FROM TMP_C
UNION
SELECT * FROM TMP_D
UNION
SELECT * FROM TMP_E
```

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Aren't the `NOT IN` parts of the `WHERE` clauses on `TMP_D` and `TMP_E` redundant?  Since the categories don't overlap, as defined in `TMP_B`, there shouldn't be any need to check anything other than category in the subsequent queries.  That makes it look like they only serve to filter out `CATEG_4` when they are `UNION`ed back together.  (Yeah, `distinct` is in there.)

Comment: @HABO: They will be redundant if the ID is unique but this is not the case. Unfortunately, ID is not unique and we can have a record with a ID = 10 and the Field_Z = TEST_1 and also a record with ID = 10 but with the Field_Z = TEST_3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, select DISTINCT will prevent duplicates from the result set, so you are overworking the condition.  By adding the "WITH" definitions and trying to nest their use makes it more confusing to follow.  The data is ultimately all coming from the "B" table where also has key match in "A".  Lets start with just that... And since you are not using anything from the (B)Field_Y or (A)Field_X in your result set, don't add them to the mix of confusion.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      B.ID,
      CASE WHEN B.Field_Z IN ('TEST_1','TEST_2') THEN 'CATEG_1'
           WHEN B.Field_Z IN ('TEST_3','TEST_4') THEN 'CATEG_2'
           WHEN B.Field_Z IN ('TEST_5','TEST_6') THEN 'CATEG_3'
           ELSE 'CATEG_4'
           END AS CATEG
   FROM
      B  JOIN  A   ON  B.ID = A.ID
   WHERE
      B.Field_Z IN ( 'TEST_1', 'TEST_2', 'TEST_3', 'TEST_4', 'TEST_5', 'TEST_6' )
```

The where clause will only include those category qualifying values you want and still have the results per each category.

Now, if you actually needed other values from your "Field_Y" or "Field_X", then that would generate a different query.  However, your Tmp_C, Tmp_D and Tmp_E are only asking for the ID and CATEG columns anyhow.

Comment: Probably stupid question: does the `UNION` have any impact on the row ordering, i.e. would the original return all TEST_1/2s before TEST_3/4s etc.? If not the original query really is crazy. (And should at least have been using `UNION ALL` not `UNION`.)

Comment: @DRapp: Effectively, we don't need the Field_X or Field_Y for this example. I just forgot to remove them from the (more complex) original query. It seems so simple now that I look at your answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Rup: No, they don't need data ordered from what I understand (this is an old query and I can just suppose what they have try to do). And this is not the only thing that was crazy !!!

Comment: @Bouzouki, if what you had was a sample of the thinking of those before you, you might want to post some more out here for help and cleanup :)

Answer (score 0):

This may perform better

```
SELECT DISTINCT B.ID, 'CATEG_1'
   FROM
      B  JOIN  A   ON  B.ID = A.ID
   WHERE
      B.Field_Z IN ( 'TEST_1', 'TEST_2')
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT B.ID, 'CATEG_2'
   FROM
      B  JOIN  A   ON  B.ID = A.ID
   WHERE
      B.Field_Z IN ( 'TEST_3', 'TEST_4')
...
```